# Unable to display submenu in blank theme of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used `<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'main menu'));?>`

To display menu and submenu in wp theme, while integrating HTML theme to wp theme but it appears in single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are printing out a [custom menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen) named 'main menu'

Just to make sure, if you go to Appearance > Menus, can you confirm that you definitely have a menu named 'main menu' and that it has submenus in it?

Comment: Yes,have created a menu named 'main menu' in appearence->menus
but all the menu and sub menu appears in single line.
,
Is it compullsory to retain the wp default style.css?

I am new to WordPress
I am using blank theme(BlankSlate)

Comment: Thanks. I have integrated html page in WordPress, but problem arises when i tried to display WordPress menues.I have also created miltilevel menues in wp-admin.

I have used wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );
to display menues.